# Assigning a random role to a player in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am relatively new to Android/Java programming. 
I am creating a text based social game and have created an SQLite Database complete with ID, Name, Role.

Roles will be assigned by the application and stored in the related SQLite table.

Since the roles are random, I was thinking maybe a random number generator from 1 - 7 (2 unique roles, 2 of the same roles and 3 of the same roles)

I am stuck on where to get started and how to implement this feature, any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would the numbers be unique? I would like all roles to be filled. So (1,2) = M, (3) = A, (4) = D, (5,6) = C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your actual task is a role assignment, you're not looking for *real* random numbers. You have a fixed set of available numbers and you want to get each number of that set *exactly once* with *no duplicates*.

The easiest way of achieving this is to put all available numbers in a list and then [*shuffle*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) it:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

You can work with any type of list, so you can skip the numbers alltogether if you're only interested in your role strings:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("M", "M", "A", "D", "C", "C");
        Collections.shuffle(roles);
        System.out.println(roles);
    }
}
```

See a [working example](http://ideone.com/vjdpY5) on ideone.

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest essence... you just want to generate a random number like so:

```
Random rand = new Random();
final int MAX_INT = 7;

int  n = rand.nextInt(MAX_INT) + 1;
//7 is the maximum and the 1 is our minimum
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about declaring each random number to a String? (e.g, 1 = M, 2 = M, 3 = A, 4 = D, 5 = C, 6 = C?)

Comment: switch (rand.nextInt(MAX_INT) + 1) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        mRole = M;
        break;
    
    case 3:
        mRole = A;
        break;
    // etc
}